# How to add a textarea to the image preview when uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xmlhttprequest

I've been struggling with this problem 3 entire days. Any help would be appreciated!

I have a button 'ADD MY PHOTO' and when clicked, it comes a popup with the option to upload a picture or more. So, when I click 'Select Files' button or I drag & drop a picture or more, it will preview the pictures on the right side.

What I need help with is: when I upload a picture or 2, I want on the right side of every picture to display a textarea where the user can write something (like a caption). Also, after the pictures and captures are displayed I need the option to remove one or all of them. Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is the CodePen code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEQMwm

Thanks in advance for help.

Also, here is the code:

```js
// ---------- THIS IS FOR THE POPUP ---------- //
  function CustomAlert() {
     this.performCustomAlert = function (dialog) {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
     }
     this.ok = function () {
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
     }
  }

  var newAlert = new CustomAlert();

  // ------------- TABS ----------------- //
  function openTab(evt, tabName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

  // ---------------- UPLOAD --------------------------//
  // ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
  let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

  // Prevent default drag behaviors
  ;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)   
    document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
  })

  // Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
  ;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
  })

  ;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
  })

  // Handle dropped files
  dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

  function preventDefaults (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  function highlight(e) {
    dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
  }

  function unhighlight(e) {
    dropArea.classList.remove('active')
  }

  function handleDrop(e) {
    var dt = e.dataTransfer
    var files = dt.files

    handleFiles(files)
  }

  let uploadProgress = []
  let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

  function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
    progressBar.value = 0
    uploadProgress = []

    for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
      uploadProgress.push(0)
    }
  }

  function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
    uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
    let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
    console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
    progressBar.value = total
  }

  function handleFiles(files) {
    files = [...files]
    initializeProgress(files.length)
    files.forEach(uploadFile)
    files.forEach(previewFile)
  }

  function previewFile(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      let img = document.createElement('img')
      img.src = reader.result
      document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
    }
  }

  function uploadFile(file, i) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var formData = new FormData()
    xhr.open('POST', true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

    // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
      updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
    })

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
      }
      else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
        // Error. Inform the user
      }
    })

    formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
    formData.append('file', file)
    xhr.send(formData)
  }
```

```css
.add-photo{
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #00a100;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 11px 13px;
    border: 3px solid #00a100;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 550;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-left: 41%;
  }

  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #dialogoverlay {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
    /*so that user can see through it*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: black;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #dialogbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 25%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
  }

  #close-popup {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    color: #474747;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100.2%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 11%;
    top: 5.4%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .content-centre{
    width: 99%;
    height: 77%;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 46px; 
  }

  #content-leftside{
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }

  .tab {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .tab button {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 14%;
    background-color: #acacac;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 6px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  }

  .tab button:hover {
    background-color: #474747;
  }

  .tab button.active {
    background-color: #474747;
  }

  .tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
  }

  #content-rightside{
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  }

  #right-topbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 9%;
    background-color: #474747;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .footer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100.2%;
    background-color: #474747;
    height: 11%;
    bottom: -5.6%;
    left: 50%;
    /* top: calc(50% - 50px); */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }


  /*------------------- UPLOAD AREA -----------------------*/

  #drop-area {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 24px auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  #progress-bar{
    display: none;
  }

  #gallery {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }

  #gallery img {
    width: 55px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px
  }

  .button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #00a100;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  #fileElem {
    display: none;
  }

  #upload-button{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #00a100;
```

```html
<button class="add-photo" onclick="newAlert.performCustomAlert()">ADD MY PHOTO</button> 
    <div class="popup-upload">
      <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
      <!--------------- SELECT MEDIA BOX ---------------->
      <div id="dialogbox">
        <!--------------- HEADER OF THE BOX ---------------->
        <div class="header">
          <!--------------- CLOSE POPUP ---------------->
          <button id="close-popup" onclick="newAlert.ok()"><i class="fa fa-times" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 7px;"></i></button>
          <div class="select-media">
              <i class="fa fa-camera" id="select-camera"></i>
              <h2 id="select-media">SELECT YOUR MEDIA</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--------------- CONTENT OF THE BOX ---------------->
        <div class="content-centre">
          <!--------------- LEFT CONTENT ---------------->
          <div id="content-leftside">
            <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openTab(event, 'Desktop')"><span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>&nbsp; Desktop</button>
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>&nbsp; Facebook</button>
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Instagram')"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>&nbsp; Instagram</button>
            </div>

            <div id="Desktop" class="tabcontent">
              <div id="drop-area">
                <form class="my-form">
                  <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload" id="upload-button"></span>
                  <p id="drag-text">Drag & Drop Your <br> Photos or Videos <br> To Upload</p>
                  <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
                  <label class="button" for="fileElem">or Select Files</label>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Facebook" class="tabcontent">
              <h3>Facebook</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="Instagram" class="tabcontent">
              <h3>Instagram</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--------------- RIGHT CONTENT ---------------->
          <div id="content-rightside">
            <!--------------- RIGHT TOPBAR ---------------->
            <div id="right-topbar">
              <h1>Selected Media</h1>
            </div>
            <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
            <div id="gallery"/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You've described what you want to do, and you've shown *a lot* of code (probably far too much)... But you haven't mentioned what's stopping you or what problem you've encountered.  What is your question?

Comment: My questions are how can I add a textarea to the image preview and how can I remove the picture along with the textarea

Comment: If you make some attempt and encounter a specific problem, we can help with that.  But I'm afraid this is not the place to find general tutoring assistance.  You are encouraged to learn more about how this community can help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @P.Pann, that's not how SO works. You don't bring a job assignment in and ask: do it for me. You're supposed to ask: I'm trying this method on this element and I'm expecting this result, as per this documentation. Why is it giving me this other result? Please add a [mcve]. Again, **minimal**. What exactly is not working in your code? Did you read specs on that method? Provide links to any of the above.

Comment: I'm just asking for some information, not for someone to do my work. So, if someone has the knowledge and knows how to do that I would be more than happy to listen :)

Comment: _“I'm just asking for some information”_ - only, you aren’t actually _asking_ anything. You need to ask _specific_ questions, describing what _exactly_ you are having trouble with. _“So, if someone has the knowledge and knows how to do that I would be more than happy to listen ”_ - nope, this site ain’t a podcast either. We are not broadcasting an endless stream of knowledge here that you would just have to tune into. If you need tutorials that explain the basics of the matter, then you need to go look for them elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look into below code, I made some changes on previewFile() function.
I hope, by looking below code you can get idea.

```js
// ---------- THIS IS FOR THE POPUP ---------- //
function CustomAlert() {
  this.performCustomAlert = function(dialog) {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
  }
  this.ok = function() {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
  }
}

var newAlert = new CustomAlert();

// ------------- TABS ----------------- //
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

// ---------------- UPLOAD --------------------------//
// ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;
['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;
['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;
['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}

let uploadProgress = []
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for (let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result

    var mainDiv = document.createElement("div")
    mainDiv.className = "box"
    mainDiv.appendChild(img)

    var textbx = document.createElement("textarea")
    textbx.placeholder ="Caption..."
    mainDiv.appendChild(textbx)

    var btn = document.createElement("button")
    var tx = document.createTextNode("X");
    btn.onclick = function() {
      $(this).closest(".box").remove()
    }
    btn.appendChild(tx);
    mainDiv.appendChild(btn)

    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(mainDiv)

  }
}

function uploadFile(file, i) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
  xhr.open('POST', true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      // Error. Inform the user
    }
  })

  formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
  formData.append('file', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

```css
  .add-photo {
  width: 18%;
  background-color: #00a100;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  border: 3px solid #00a100;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 550;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-left: 41%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#dialogoverlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*so that user can see through it*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#dialogbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 25%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
  animation: fadeEffect 0.3s;
}

#close-popup {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100.2%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 11%;
  top: 5.4%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.content-centre {
  width: 99%;
  height: 77%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 46px;
}

#content-leftside {
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab button {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 14%;
  background-color: #acacac;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #474747;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #474747;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#content-rightside {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#right-topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9%;
  background-color: #474747;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100.2%;
  background-color: #474747;
  height: 11%;
  bottom: -5.6%;
  left: 50%;
  /* top: calc(50% - 50px); */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*------------------- UPLOAD AREA -----------------------*/

#drop-area {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 24px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#progress-bar {
  display: none;
}

#gallery {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 55px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #00a100;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#fileElem {
  display: none;
}

#upload-button {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #00a100;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-photo" onclick="newAlert.performCustomAlert()">ADD MY PHOTO</button>
<div class="popup-upload">
  <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
  <!--------------- SELECT MEDIA BOX ---------------->
  <div id="dialogbox">
    <!--------------- HEADER OF THE BOX ---------------->
    <div class="header">
      <!--------------- CLOSE POPUP ---------------->
      <button id="close-popup" onclick="newAlert.ok()"><i class="fa fa-times" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 7px;"></i></button>
      <div class="select-media">
        <i class="fa fa-camera" id="select-camera"></i>
        <h2 id="select-media">SELECT YOUR MEDIA</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--------------- CONTENT OF THE BOX ---------------->
    <div class="content-centre">
      <!--------------- LEFT CONTENT ---------------->
      <div id="content-leftside">
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openTab(event, 'Desktop')"><span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>&nbsp; Desktop</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>&nbsp; Facebook</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Instagram')"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>&nbsp; Instagram</button>
        </div>

        <div id="Desktop" class="tabcontent">
          <div id="drop-area">
            <form class="my-form">
              <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload" id="upload-button"></span>
              <p id="drag-text">Drag & Drop Your <br> Photos or Videos <br> To Upload</p>
              <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
              <label class="button" for="fileElem">or Select Files</label>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Facebook" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Facebook</h3>
        </div>

        <div id="Instagram" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Instagram</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--------------- RIGHT CONTENT ---------------->
      <div id="content-rightside">
        <!--------------- RIGHT TOPBAR ---------------->
        <div id="right-topbar">
          <h1>Selected Media</h1>
        </div>
        <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
        <div id="gallery" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

just replace previewFile function with this.

```
  function previewFile(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
     var gallleryDiv=document.getElementById('gallery');
     var wrapperDiv = document.createElement("div");
     let img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src = reader.result;
     wrapperDiv.className = "wrapperDiv";
     wrapperDiv.appendChild(img)
     var textbx = document.createElement("textarea");
     wrapperDiv.appendChild(textbx);
     var btn = document.createElement("button");
     var tx = document.createTextNode("X");
     btn.onclick = function() {$(this).closest(".wrapperDiv").remove()}
     btn.appendChild(tx);
     wrapperDiv.appendChild(btn);
     gallleryDiv.appendChild(wrapperDiv);
    }
  }
```